# Flutter imagepicker with getX

Tags: flutter, imagepicker, flutter-getx

This is yet another my adventure learning getx dealing with image. I've taken this code from another source but it didn't solve my problem. I suited with my own example. How do I update my BoxDecoration widget with a selected image?

The following is my widget

```
            GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => {_onPictureSelection()},
            child:Container(
              height: screenHeight / 3.2,
              width: screenWidth / 1.8,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: imageController.image == null
                      ? AssetImage(pathAsset)
                      : FileImage(imageController.image),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 3.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(5.0) //         <--- border radius here
                    ),
              ),
            )),

           _onPictureSelection() async {
              imageController.getImage();
            }
```

and this is my imagecontroller

```
class ImageController extends GetxController {
static ImageController get to => Get.find<ImageController>();

File image;
String imagePath;
final _picker = ImagePicker();

Future<void> getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

if (pickedFile != null) {
  image = File(pickedFile.path);
  imagePath = pickedFile.path;
  print(imagePath);
  update();
 } else {
  print('No image selected.');
 }
}
}
```

How can I update my BoxDecoration widget with an image taken through the camera and where do wrap obx with my widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much try and error finally I've got it.

I updated my GestureDetector widget with GetBuilder

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => {_onPictureSelection()},
            child: GetBuilder<ImageController>(
                // specify type as Controller
                init: ImageController(), // intialize with the Controller
                builder: (value) => Container(
                      height: screenHeight / 3.2,
                      width: screenWidth / 1.8,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: imageController.image == null
                              ? AssetImage(pathAsset)
                              : FileImage(imageController.image),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        border: Border.all(
                          width: 3.0,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(
                                5.0) //         <--- border radius here
                            ),
                      ),
                    ))),
```

and finally it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the below condition in your code in **ImageController** Class.

```
if (pickedFile != null) {
    image = File(pickedFile.path);
    imagePath = pickedFile.path;
    print(imagePath);
    update();
} else {
   print('No image selected.');
}
```

Comment: I did update but the widget didn't update with the image captured.

Comment: you can also use : 

image: imageController.image == null
                      ? AssetImage(pathAsset)
                      : Image.file(File(imageController.imagePath)),
OR
image: imageController.image == null
                      ? AssetImage(pathAsset)
                      : Image.file(imageController.image),

Comment: yes i did that but how do i update the widget once the image captured. when i tried obx, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as it is

```
 Future pickImageCamera() async {
try {
  final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
  if (image == null) return;
  final imageTemp = File(image.path);
  this.image = imageTemp;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print('Failed to pick image: $e');
}
update();
```

}
====>>
2. To set the image

```
 GetBuilder<VehicleDetailsController>(builder: (controller) {
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 12),
              child: vehicleController.image != null
                  ? Image.file(
                      vehicleController.image!,
                      height: size.height * 0.35,
                      width: size.width,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    )
                  : Container(
                      height: size.height * 0.35,
                      width: size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppThemeData.perano),
                    ),
            );
          }),
```